# Combine multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like this;

```
Id  Name        Number  Birthdate   
0   Dajit Singh NULL    6/9/2007  
5   Dajit Singh 12345   NULL   
11  Dajit Singh NULL    NULL
```

I want to progammatically combine these rows into 1 row with all data available:

```
0   Dajit Singh 12345   6/9/2007
```

Here's what I've got so far, but it doesn't do it:

```
Select Id, 
       Max(Name)   As Name, 
       Max(Number)    As Number, 
       Max(Birthdate) As Birthdate 
From   tblPerson 
Group By Id, Name, Number, Birthdate
Order By Name
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Use `MIN(Id)` instead of just `Id`.

Comment: If you want the outcome you put in your description just change ID to Min(ID) as ID and take out the entire Group By or group by Name only since that is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the script:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Id          INT NOT NULL,
    Name        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Number      INT NULL,
    Birthdate   DATETIME NULL
)


INSERT INTO @table(Id, Name, Number, Birthdate) VALUES
(0, 'Dajit Singh', NULL, '20070906'),
(5, 'Dajit Singh', 12345, NULL),
(11, 'Dajit Singh', NULL, NULL),
(100, 'Alex', NULL, '20080906'),
(500, 'Alex', 12345, NULL),
(1100, 'Alex', NULL, NULL)


SELECT
    MIN(Id) As Id, 
    Name As Name, 
    MAX(Number) As Number, 
    MAX(Birthdate) As Birthdate 
FROM @table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```